# Java- Reversing Text in a document

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program that will read a file, copy it, and reverse the text- meaning the last word in the document is now the first. The method I created does not reverse when moved to the output file.

```
public static ArrayList<String> fileLines(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    while (fileRead.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileRead.nextLine();
        lines.add(line);
    }
    fileRead.close();
    return lines;
}

public static void writeLinesReverse(ArrayList<String> lines, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter fileWrite = new PrintWriter(new File(filename));
    for (int i = lines.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        fileWrite.write(lines.get(i));
    }
    fileWrite.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `Collections.reverse` to reverse the arraylist

Maybe something like this

```
//reverse list
Collections.reverse(lines);

for (String s: lines) {
   //write to file
}
```

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))

Answer (score 0):

// Reverse the complete line

```
    while (fileRead.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileRead.nextLine();
        lines.add(new StringBuffer(line).reverse().toString());
    }
```

input: ***Stack overflow***

output: **wolfrevo kcatS**

If you want to reverse the content of word in each line,

1) First read the line

2) Use split() function to get individual words in the line

3) Create StringBuffer on each word and reverse it as shown above.

If you follow this approach,

output will be

**kcatS wolfrevo**